# Azure MobileService EasyApi java.lang.interruptedException

Tags: javascript, java, azure, express, azure-mobile-services

in my MobileService I defined new easy api "test". 
Right now from Android I'm trying to invoke simple request to get my passed object filled:

```
  Exists result = mClient.invokeApi("test","ID" ,Exists.class).get();
```

Where Exists is defined as

```
public class Exists {
    public boolean Exists;
}
```

My test.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "post": function (req, res, next) {
 res.json({"Exists": "true"});
 res.send();
    }
};
```

This return me  java.lang.interruptedException. Could somebody explain me why and how could i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, service was turned off